# SingleOrDefault, how to write out default?

Tags: c#, linq

My below query

```
 var varUser = (from d in db.tblUsers where (d.ID == intID) select d).SingleOrDefault();
 return varUser.Forename + " " + varUser.Surname;
```

When using single or default how do I output a default value?
so forename and surname is empty i want to wirte "No User" instead

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if user is `null` (default case) and return some default value (or throw exception)

```
if (varUser == null)
    return "No User"; // default value or exception

return String.Format("{0} {1}", varUser.Forename, varUser.Surname);
```

---

**HINT**: You can pass condition to [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534956.aspx) method:

```
db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == intID)
```

Or even use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) if you are using Entity Framework (internally it calls SingleOrDefault if entity cannot be found in entities tracked by context)

```
db.tblUsers.Find(intID)
```

Comment: i dont know what you mean with regards to passing value to single or default? could i put singleordeafult("No User") ?

Comment: @AlexW I mean condition from `where` clause - you can pass it to `SingleOrDefault`. Query is match shorter in this case

Comment: And what if the type of varUser is a value type and not a reference type?

Comment: @NickWhaley then you will not be able to use EF or Linq to SQL. BTW mutable structs are evil

Answer (score 1):

```
return var varUser = db.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id == intID) ?? "No User";
```

Comment: And where is "John Smith"?

Comment: John Smith went to the pub

Comment: Actually your code will not compile and will not return full name string

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return varUser == null ? "No User" :
 string.Concat(varUser.Forename, " " , varUser.Surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a read-only property to your user class:

```
Public Class User
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property FullName() As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) Then
                Return "No Name"
            Else
                Return FirstName & " " & LastName
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now you can use your LINQ statement like this (*DefaultIfEmpty* clause):

```
Dim varUser = (From d In db.tblUsers Where (d.ID == intID) Select d).DefaultIfEmpty(New User).SingleOrDefault()

Return varUser.FullName
```

Sorry am not proficient in C# hence the VB code. But you get the idea.